# Please reopen this "on hold" question

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-reopen

[What can we infer about the programming language used in "Jurassic Park" (the book, not the movie)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135417/what-can-we-infer-about-the-programming-language-used-in-jurassic-park-the-bo)

It seems that putting a question "on hold" disables the ability to post answers, so that an "on hold" question by definition can never attract good answers (because it cannot attract any answers).

Comment: Since you seem to be unfamiliar with the SE model of closing questions, [here's a link](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) which may help you to learn more about it in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just cast the final vote to reopen. In my opinion it's not a *good* question, but it's also not off-topic given its reference to the text of a scifi novel.

I suspect it will spawn a bunch of highly guesswork-oriented answers as well as some code rants. That being said, I  stand ready to be pleasantly surprised if it turns out to be something interesting.